# For looping through a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, sum

I'm trying to for loop through a dictionary and print the first float value of every row but I have no idea how to choose that I want just those values.

My dictionary:

```
{'abc': 123123, 'defg': [
    ['123.4', '10'],
    ['567.8', '10'],
    ['91011.12', '10']
]}
```

I want the output to be:

```
123.4
567.8
91011.12
```

Also I want to sum those values. Is there easier way to do that with SUM method without looping?

Thanks for the help! I'm really lost with this.

Comment: But the item of `'abc'` is not a list (nor a list of list)... Should we only process items of the dictionary that are lists of lists? What have you tried?

Comment: Ever seen the [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function?

Comment: `sum(x[0] for x in mydict['defg'])`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with looping, just give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I got it. Thanks to Ajax1234 and Jerfov2 for tips!

```
s = {'abc': 123123, 'defg': [
['123.4', '10'],
['567.8', '10'],
['91011.12', '10']
]}
```

For loop and print:

```
for x in s['defg']:
    print(x[0])
```

Outputs:

```
123.4
567.8
91011.12
```

And the summing with for loop:

```
summed = 0
for x in s['defg']:
    summed = summed + float(x[0])
print("%.2f" % summed)
```

Outputs:

```
91702.32
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very end any functional approach in Python is just syntactic sugar, here are my 2 cents in a non-functional fashion:

```
import ast
import itertools

s = {'abc': 123123, 'defg': [
    ['123.4', '10'],
    ['567.8', '10'],
    ['91011.12', '10']
]}

def str_is_float(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        value = ast.literal_eval(value)
    if isinstance(value, float):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def get_floats(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for n in itertools.chain.from_iterable(v):
                if str_is_float(n):
                    yield float(n) 
        elif str_is_float(v):
            yield float(v)

floats = list(get_floats(s))

# Print all the floats
print(floats) 
# sum the floats
print(sum(x for x in floats))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `reduce` for a more functional solution:

```
import re
import itertools
from functools import reduce
s = {'abc': 123123, 'defg': [
 ['123.4', '10'],
['567.8', '10'],
['91011.12', '10']
]}
new_s = list(itertools.chain(*[[float(c) for c in itertools.chain(*b) if re.findall('^\d+\.\d+$', c)] for a, b in s.items() if isinstance(b, list)]))
print(new_s)
print(reduce(lambda x, y:x+y, new_s))
```

Output:

```
[123.4, 567.8, 91011.12]
91702.32
```